# CreateRemoteThread before DLL's are loaded

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to inject my code to another process using CreateRemoteThread, but if my code is being injected while process is loading DLL's, thread becomes frozen until DLL's are loaded (it is OK according to MSDN). I have tried to detect if process is loaded by injecting code and waiting for result and checking EAX then, but it is very slow.

So, I'm looking for method to check if process is still loading DLL's or it has all DLL's loaded and I can call CreateRemoteThread to wait my code being executed immediately.

Comment: "Has all DLL's loaded" is undefined for an arbitrary process. Think `LoadLibrary` calls.

Comment: Why is it a problem that your thread is waiting while dlls are loaded?

Comment: It is a problem because my application is looping through processes, so other process could start while my process is checking if DLL's are loaded.

Comment: Well, use a different thread for each process.

Comment: I can not create different thread in each 20 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `HANDLE` to the target process, try using `WaitForInputIdle()` before calling `CreateRemoteThread()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Debug API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), run your target process as a debugee and have your injecting process be the "debugger", you will then get informed of all of the DLL load/unload events and also when the process is loaded and ready to run (you hit the "loader breakpoint"). It gets more complex for x64 and more complex still if you're trying to inject into managed code but it works pretty well.

I have several tools which use this method ([here](http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2006/04/tickshifter-v02.html) and [here](http://www.lockexplorer.com/)) no source code available, sorry.

If what you are trying to do is hook various APIs, then the canonical way of doing this is to always also hook `LoadLibrary()` so that you can hook any NEW DLLs that are loaded whilst the process is running. I still find it useful, however, to control the target process using the debug api as it makes it easier to hook as soon as you can (at loader breakpoint, before you resume the process).

Comment: Thank you, it is a good solution, but is there an asynchronous API (with immediate return) that can be used for checking, if process had been initialized or not?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Sounds like a very specialist function with limited use - what exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps you should be doing it in a different way?